# No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.Design.TabLayout'

Tags: android

I linked a module to an android project through settings.gradle but I got copmpile errors.

Error:(470, 5) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.Design.TabLayout'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to update build gradle settings of the imported modulecompile

add this line
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'